# Equality in a discrete isoperimetric inequality

Tags: combinatorics

For a subset $A \subset \mathcal{P}(\{1,...,n\})$ I have seen the following bound on the edge boundary:

$|\partial A| \ge |A|(n-\log_2|A|)$

there is certainly equality whenever $A$ is a "subcube" of the discrete cube but I was wondering if this is the only possible equality case and if so how can I prove it?

Comment: I don't understand what graph you are working with. What is the vertex set and what are the edges?